# `uname -m` differs from `arch` after deployed an El Capitan VM with Virtualbox (5.x)

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-elcapitan, cpuid, xnu

I am going to get an El Capitan virtual machine. I have a VirtualBox v5.1.6 which runs on a CentOS-7.2/i5-6042P x64 machine. I followed the steps 'https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-pc-on-virtualbox/', which finally helps me to get my El Capitan VM. But an odd thing that makes me confused. Please see the CLI output below.

localhost:~ sid$ uname -a

Darwin localhost 15.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Wed Aug 26 16:57:32 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3247.1.106~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

localhost:~ sid$ arch

i386

localhost:~ sid$ uname -m

x86_64

localhost:~ sid$

I guess it was set with a wrong CPUID (just a guess...). So, please correct me if something wrong. Thanks in advance!

--
Sid

Comment: typo :-( ...   the CPU is i5-6402P

Comment: on my Mac Book Pro, same output as above :-(